# How to count number of distinct words within a string?

Tags: ruby, string

I would like to write a method which takes a string and returns the number of distinct words within the string.

I initially began using `split` to then `map` over the array, but after looking into many methods I'm completely stumped on how to then compare one value to another value within the same array.

Comment: `str.split.uniq.count` maybe

Comment: Since "word" can mean different things, you might want to be a little more specific (define what makes a word). A few examples might help too.

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider various ways of doing that.

- All of the following have the limitation that they do not deal with hyphenated words ("don't" or "wouldn't've") or contractions ("so-so" or "mother-in-law").
- Strings may contain punctuation or substrings that are not words ("$79.21"). We may attempt to remove those characters as an initial step or simply disregard them. I have chosen the latter approach.
- We would like "bugaboo" and "Bugaboo" to be regarded as the same word so the first step might be to downcase (or upcase) the string.

Let's work with the following string (the beginning of a rather long sentence penned by Chuck Dickens).

```
str = "It was the best of times, it was the worst of times."
```

---

```
def find_em(str)
  str.downcase.scan(/[a-z]+/).uniq.size
end
```

```
find_em(str) #=> 7
```

Note that

```
str.downcase.scan(/[a-z]+/).uniq
  #=> ["it", "was", "the", "best", "of", "times", "worst"]
```

The *regular expression* `/[a-z]+/` matches one or more lowercase letters, as many as possible.

See [String#scan](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-scan) and [Array#uniq](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-uniq).

---

Notice that the previous method produces an intermediate array `str.downcase.scan(/[a-z]+/)`. We could avoid that as follows.

```
def find_em(str)
  str.downcase.gsub(/[a-z]+/).with_object([]) do |s,a|
    a << s unless a.include?(s)
  end.size
end
```

```
find_em(str) #=> 7
```

This employs the (rarely-used) form of [String#gsub](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) that takes an argument but no block, producing an enumerator. It merely enumerates matches of the regular expression `/[a-z]+/` and therefore has nothing to do with string substitution.

---

The previous method works but has the disadvantage of employing a linear search (`a.include?(s)`) for each word `s` found. We can remedy that problem by constructing a set (which by definition has unique elements) and then converting it to an array at the end.

```
def find_em(str)
  str.downcase.gsub(/[a-z]+/).with_object(Set.new) { |s,st| st << s }.size
end
```

```
find_em str
  #=> 7
```

See [Set::new](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html#method-c-new), [Set#<<](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html#method-i-3C-3C) and [Set#include?](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html#method-i-include-3F).

---

Another variant is to use `scan` with a more complex regular expression. I will express this regular expression in *free-spacing mode* to make it self-documenting.

```
RGX = /
      (         # begin capture group 1
        \b      # match a word boundary
        [a-z]+  # match one or more lowercase letters
        \b      # match a word boundary
      )         # end capture group 1
      (?!       # begin negative lookahead
        .*      # match zero or more characters
        \b      # match a word boundary
        \1      # match the contents of capture group 1
        \b      # match a word boundary
      )         # end negative lookahead
      /x        # use free-spacing regex definition mode

def find_em(str)
  str.downcase.scan(RGX).size
end
```

```
find_em(str) #=> 7
```

Note that

```
str.downcase.scan(RGX)    
  #=> [["best"], ["it"], ["was"], ["the"], ["worst"], ["of"], ["times"]]
```

This regular expression is conventionally written

```
/(\b[a-z]+\b)(?!.*\b\1\b)/
```

---

Alternatively, we could use that weird form of `gsub`, which avoids the construction of arrays altogether.

```
def find_em(str)
  str.downcase.gsub(RGX).count
end
```

```
find_em(str) #=> 7
```

See [Enumerator#count](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-count).